# Loop array for scrape

Tags: php

I have an array with some values

```
$array = array("Bob","jim","frank","pat");
```

And i have some scrape code from simple html dom

```
$html = file_get_html('http://somesite.com?search=name');
//itteration and so on
```

I want to be able to give the url the values from the array one at a time so it will scrape the url with search=bob then go to search=jim and so on

I tried putting the file_get_html with the itterations and so on in a loop then use

```
foreach($array as $arrays){
$html = file_get_html('http://somesite.com?search=$arrays');
//more code
}
```

But this wont work, anyway to do this?

Comment: Side note: `foreach($array as $arrayS)` doesn't make sense, i would name it something like `foreach($array as $name)` :p

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `"` instead of `'`. The `double quotes` allow variables to be used within a string. Alternatively use `concatenation`:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://somesite.com?search=' . $arrays);
```